# How do I install the Standard-Library for Agda on Windows?

Tags: windows, agda, standard-library

I have created a file libraries.txt in C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\agda
and I have inserted the path to the standard library as it was installed on my pc : "C:\Users\name\Desktop\agda-stdlib-master\standard-library.agda-lib" and it says I can't find it.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name should be called libraries  (without extension) instead of libraries.txt. You might need to do this from the command prompt (move libries.txt libraries)